# program where user Enter a New Integer Value•Print Pointer Address•Print Integer Address•

Tags: c, loops, pointers, int, indirection

When I use choice switch for cases it fails to repeat.
program #1Create a program in which allows the user to select one of the following four menu operations:
Enter a New Integer Value

- Print Pointer Address
- Print Integer Address
- Print integer Value

For this program you need to create two variables:

- one integer data type
- one pointer

Using indirection, assign any new integer value that the user enters through an appropriate pointer
Have the program ask if the user would like to try again, and loop according

Comment: And your code is ....

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Formatted the question